# Cookie set in Dev, but not in Prod

Tags: javascript, database, graphql, apollo

My graphql/apollo server has the following mutation:

```
  async signup(parent, args, ctx, info) {
    args.email = args.email.toLowerCase();
    const password = await bcrypt.hash(args.password, 10);
    const user = await ctx.db.mutation.createUser(
      {
        data: {
          ...args,
          password,
          permissions: { set: ["USER"] }
        }
      },
      info
    );

    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.APP_SECRET);

    ctx.response.cookie("token", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 // 1 year cookie
    });

    return user;
  },
```

During local development, the cookie is set as soon as a new user signs up. This will aid in logging the new user in right away. Once pushed up to Now & Heroku, however, the user is created in the DB but the cookie never gets set.

I'm not sure where to begin debugging this as there is no console output on the prod server.

Please let me know what else to add into this and I will edit.

Comment: Do you see the `Set-Cookie` header in the server's response?

Comment: no, one is the data i just used to register the new person, and the other is `{"data":{"me":null}}`

Comment: I had similar problems as well. This is for sure very annoying to test. You said the cookie is not set in the response, right? Does your GraphQL API run on a different domain than your app? Maybe you need to set the `domain` option.

Comment: @jkettmann Yes, the DB is hosted on Heroku, the Yoga server runs on Now.sh and the frontend again on Heroku. What is the domain option? if you mean whitelisting the urls for cors, i already did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is for all the folks who had a blond moment like me.
Across multiple different browsers there was one setting that effectively hindered the cookie from being set.

The Chrome setting is called

```
Block third-party cookies
Prevent third-party websites from saving and reading cookie data.
```

Blew my mind I hadn't thought of this before, but this setting is what prevented my app from working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well when I was hosting the GraphQL API on a different domain or port than my app's domain. If that's the case you need to set the `domain` option when setting the cookie as below:

```
ctx.response.cookie("token", token, {
  httpOnly: true,
  maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 // 1 year cookie
  domain: 'your-app-domain.com',
});
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Per MDN docs, it "specifies those hosts to which the cookie will be sent. If not specified, defaults to the host portion of the current document location." The cookie is generated ON the yoga server, so setting the yoga server url will do the trick you think? I tried both on the signup, and signin mutation and it didn't work. Still playing with this option though.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. You should use the app's domain, not the server domain. I updated the answer.